# Making a twitter auto reply program

Tags: twitter

So I have a dedicated server and I want to make an auto reply program so whenever someone tweets my account I will automatically reply with a choice of 4 tweets, the tweet that is chosen is randomized.

How could I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You build a daemon that checks every n seconds (or minutes) if you have a new message. To do that, you can use the twitter-api. If so, you respond using the twitter-api.

Instead of a daemon you could also write a script and use a cronjob to execute it automatically every n minutes.

Edit: To get more information ask more detailed.

Comment: http://ctrlq.org/code/19420-twitter-autoresponder I was trying to use that link but that doesn't allow for more than one randomized response and when I tried to run it in google scripts I was getting an error on line 70 ReferenceError: "ScriptDb" is not defined. (line 70, file "Code")

Comment: [accidentally deleted my comment, again:] Add the var `MESSAGE` in the `start`-function as an array with you messages. Update `OUTOFOFFICE_MESSAGE` to a random entry of `MESSAGES` at the beginning of the `outOfOffice`-function. (Quick fix, kind of dirty)